# Data scraping from OECD

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am working with OECD package version "0.2.4". Now I want to download some migration data

Now I want to download some migration data

```
library(OECD)

dataset <-"DIOC_CITIZEN_AGE"
dstruc<-get_data_structure(dataset)

filter_list<-list(c("FYUG-MKD"))
data.migration<-get_dataset(dataset = dataset, filter = filter_list,
                            start_time= 2010, end_time= 2020)
head(data.migration)
```

When I try to execute this I received error `Bad Request (HTTP 400).Error in rsdmx::readSDMX(url) : HTTP request failed with status: 400`

Can anybody help me how to solve this error ?

Comment: [Possibly relevant](https://github.com/expersso/OECD/issues/26)?

Comment: silent_hunter the OECD package appears to be abandonware. I can't even get the examples in their documentation working rip

Comment: @Mark I can't agree with this. I can download other data but I can't this dataset